# incomprehensible behavior during firebase and firestore update / authentication

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an authentication code and updating of users role, everything goes well except during user updating, the session connects with the user that I have just modified. From my checks I find that right after updating the user it enters the ForEach. This problem does not occur when for example I refresh the page or the first time, it is when I switch from one session to another (signin) and I modify the user it changes session. I looked well I do not understand this behavior, if possible to give me help. Thank you in advance.

here is my code :

// USER DATA

```
  userDataChanges: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.userData);

  setUserData(userData: any): void {
    this.userData = userData;
    this.userDataChanges.next(userData);
  }
```

// SIGNIN

```
  SignIn(email: string, password: string) {

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

      .then((user) => {

        this.firestore.collection("users").ref.where("uid", "==", user.user.uid).onSnapshot(snap => {
          snap.forEach(userRef => {

            this.userData = userRef.data();

            //INIT USER
            this.SetUserData(this.userData);

            this.router.navigate(['postsignin']);

          })

        })

      }).catch(err => err)
  }
```

// UPDATE USER ROLE

```
  updateFirebaseUser(uid: string, role: string) {
    this.firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).update({ roles: role });
  }
```

// SIGNOUT

```
   SignOut() {

    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {

      localStorage.setItem('user', null);
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

      this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(["/sign-in"]));
    })
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you point out which specific line in your code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: thanks, the authentication is going correctly, but when I call the update function updateFirebaseUser(uid: string, role: string)  to update the role of another existing user, I see that my session disconnects and reconnects with the user that I modified. When I checked with consoles.log I noticed that when I do an update the code is triggered in ForEach and suddenly reconnects with the user that I wanted to modify.While I simply want to modify an existing user in base without more.

Comment: Of you modify the user, it is expected behavior for the `onSnapshot` to fire again. If you don't want to be notified of such updates, use `get()` instead.

Comment: I made this modification and it works you saved my weekend thank you very much for your efficiency :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify a document, it is expected behavior for the `onSnapshot` that observes that document to fire again.

If you don't want to be notified of such updates, use `get()` instead.